# HOW CAN I CHECK FOR NULL VALUES WITHOUT var_dump()? PHP

Tags: php

even after commenting out the echo function its still displaying null on a null value.i jx want ti use it a function not to output.

```
<?php 
     if (var_dump($row['display_photo']) === null) {
            //echo "null";
            }else {
            echo "not null";
            }
?>
```

Comment: you can use empty: `if(empty($row['display_photo']))` http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Did you try to remove `var_dump` function from your condition?

Comment: `isset($row['display_photo'])` is sufficient "_Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL_". also, where in the world did you get the idea that var_dump() would be a good idea inside of a conditional statement like that?

Comment: thanx for the responses....i have settled with is_null().

Comment: Will the index `$row['display_photo']` always exist?

Comment: @Scuzzy i get your point..that would return an error if i doesnt exist ryt

Comment: `isset()` will not raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset` or `empty` functions.

```
<?php 
     if (empty($row['display_photo'])) {
            //echo "null";
            }else {
            echo "not null";
            }
?>
```

Comment: `0` is empty and not null